# Issue with layout

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, interface-builder, autolayout

I've got a small problem with the way my app looks. I don't want to see that shift at the top of the screen. While creating this scene in IB there isn't one, but it appears when I launch the app. I would be really grateful if anyone could help my to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can't get Your question please Explain it .

Comment: if anything can be told - you have your layout wrong =D
You should provide more info.

Comment: Show us the constraints you have set.

Comment: Have you tried this   "self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;"   in viewDidLoad method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this as follows:

1. In your storyboard, select the view controller that is giving the issue (You can use the yellow icon on top of view controller to select it).
2. Click on the attribute inspector
3. Uncheck the 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'

[image]